# Is it allowed to use procedural functions inside OOP PHP methods?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, oop, methods

I am learning Object oriented PHP and I am wondering if it is allowed to use procedural functions inside methods.

For example in [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) you have a function `get_option();` to get a value by name from the options database table. Is it allowed to do something like this:

```
class ExampleClass {

   public static function ExampleMethod( $optionName ) {
      if( get_option( $optionName ) ) {
         return get_option( $optionName ) + 20;
      }     
   }

}
```

Comment: Take a simple example: *How would you get the length of a string, when you wouldn't be allowed to use functions like `strlen()` in a class?* So yes it does work, yes it is allowed and yes it's also used.

Comment: This is what I thought, but I needed confirmation. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You're welcome :) Also just to note this here: If you use namespaces you have to watch out: `namespace I_AM_A_NAMESPACE;
 function strlen() { echo "nope"; }
    echo strlen("xyz"); echo \strlen("xyz");` First function call will print "nope", second "3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it allowed to use procedural functions inside OOP PHP methods?

Well the first question would be is it even possible. And why don't we try it out:

```
class A {

    public static function randomStaticMethod() {
        echo "Function call:" . phpversion();
    }

    public function randomMethod() {
        echo "Function call:" . phpversion();
    }

}

$o = new A();
$o->randomMethod();

A::randomStaticMethod();
```

And you will see it will work as expected, no errors no warnings, just:

```
Function call: ...
Function call: ...
```

So it's definitely possible. Now to your question: Is it allowed?

Simple question, which should answer your question:

> How would you get the length of a string, when you wouldn't be allowed to use functions like `strlen()` in a class?

So yes it's also definitely allowed and used.

---

Now a few other things, which might be useful to know. If you work with namespaces you have to be careful.

As example:

```
namespace I_AM_A_NAMESPACE;

function strlen() {
    echo "nope";
}

echo strlen("xyz");
echo \strlen("xyz");
```

Your output will be:

```
nope
3
```

So if you work with namespaces you have to know in which namespace you are and which function you want to call. So if you want to call the global function `strlen()` and you want to take the save route, always put a `\` in front of it, to make sure you call the global `strlen()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could go completely static with the code below. I just used the number 1 as the parameter and I used `Return 1` as example code so something can be returned. I'd personally recommend allocating objects dynamically especially if your system has limited memory, but here's my code:

```
<?php
echo ExampleClass::ExampleMethod(1);
exit();

class ExampleClass {

public static function get_option( $optionName ) {
    //do processing here
return 1;
}

public static function ExampleMethod( $optionName ) {
if( ExampleClass::get_option( $optionName ) ) {
    return ExampleClass::get_option( $optionName ) + 20;
}
}

}
?>
```